# Compute the sum of a sequence of object values inside a System.Array instance

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code:

```
private object Add(object a, object b)
{
    // Assume: a and b are the same types.
    // Assume: a and b are numeric types (ex. int).

    Array array = Array.CreateInstance(a.GetType(), 2);
    array.SetValue(a, 0);
    array.SetValue(b, 1);

    // Is it possible to return the Sum of the values inside the Array instance?
}
```

There are many alternative (and of course better) ways to do this using a regular array, generics or avoid passing object and just pass int, double, etc.

Just trying to figure out if this is possible at all (without the use of dynamic primitive type).

Comment: If the types are object how do you define the addition operation? The compiler won't like the fact that you are trying to add two 'object' unless it can infer how to add them.

Comment: @Icarus it's true. With the dynamic primitive type it can infer it. But it seems its not possible with some other way. :(

Comment: Generics will fail you here too, but C++ templates would work just fine.

Comment: It would be nice to have a 'where T implements a XXX operator' generics constraint....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the array contains only ints, you can do that:

```
int sum = array.Cast<int>().Sum();
```

If the array contains integer numeric values, but you don't know their type, you can try something like that:

```
long sum = array.Cast<object>().Select(o => Convert.ToInt64(o)).Sum();
```